# PHP DOM parsing to get to elements inside specific div id

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I have some html as follows:

```
<div id="tvcap">
    <div class="c" id="tads">
        <ol>
            <li>
                <div class="vsc vsta">
                    <h3>
                        <a id="pa1" href="">
                        </a>
                        <a id="vpa1" href="http://www.link1.com">
                        Link 1 Text 1</a>
                    </h3>

                    <div>
                        <div class="kv kva">
                            <cite>
                            www.link1.com</cite>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <span class="ac">Link 1 Text2</span>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li>
                <div class="vsc vsta">
                <h3>
                <a id="pa2" href="">
                </a>
                <a id="vpa2" href="http://www.link2.com">Link 2 Text 1</a>
                </h3>

                <div>
                    <div class="kv kva">
                    <cite>www.link2.com</cite>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <span class="ac">Link 2 Text 3</span>
                <div>
                <div class="oslk">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

Potentially there will be an unknown number of the links&texts, and I wish to iterate and be able to get to each link and text.

I am using the [simple html dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

I cannot find the command to get to the div id 'vpa1'.

I tried this, but it returns nothing:

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
 if ($element->id == "vpa1") echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

How can I get to each link and text based on the id being vpa[$i] (vpa1, vpa2, etc).

Comment: If you know `XPath`... things become more simple. Actual speedy nuilt-in `DOM` has the `xpath` abilities. I do not now whether this 'simple html dom parser' has it...

Comment: @Wrikken How would you do it with XPath ? (I do not have to use the simple html dom parser)

Comment: `$xpath->query("//a[starts-with(@id,'vpa')]");` for instance, depends on the rest of the html.

Answer (score 5):

**Function to extract the contents from a specific div id from any webpage**

The below function extracts the contents from the specified div and returns it. If no divs with the ID are found, it returns false.

```
function getHTMLByID($id, $html) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $node = $dom->getElementById($id);
    if ($node) {
        return $dom->saveXML($node);
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

`$id` is the ID of the `<div>` whose content you're trying to extract, `$html` is your HTML markup.

Usage example:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.mysql.com/');
echo getHTMLByID('tagline', $html);
```

Output:

```
The world's most popular open source database
```

Answer (score 3):

as @Wrikken  said, Xpath will be not fast, but simple solution.

Here code, which you can use as start point:

```php
        $some_html = file_get_contents('some_html.html'); // i put your html into some_html.html file   

        $doc = new DOMDocument();    
        $doc->loadHtml($some_html); // $some_html should contain your html string    

        $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);    

        //process with no bugs    
        $result = $xpath->query('//*[@id="vpa1"]');    

        var_dump($result);    

        if (!empty($result)) {    
                foreach ( $result as $link ) {    
                        var_dump($link->nodeValue);    
                }    
        } 
        // output  
        // object(DOMNodeList)#4 (1) { ["length"]=> int(1) } string(38) " Link 1 Text 1"

        $result = $xpath->query('//a');    
        var_dump($result);    

        if (!empty($result)) {    
                foreach ( $result as $link ) {    
                        var_dump($link->nodeValue);    
                }    
        }    
        // output
        // object(DOMNodeList)#8 (1) { ["length"]=> int(4) } string(25) " " string(38) " Link 1 Text 1" string(17) " " string(13) "Link 2 Text 1"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. For some reason the command '$result = $xpath->query('//*[@id="vpa1"]')' does not work. The url is "https://www.google.fr/webhp?hl=fr&tab=ww#hl=fr&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=site+web&oq=site+web&gs_l=hp.3..0l4.5270.7234.0.7379.8.5.0.3.3.0.80.365.5.5.0...0.0...1c.1.XZIIRR9I0mU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355272958,d.Yms&fp=b0a66e3037608269&bpcl=39942515&biw=1366&bih=677"

Comment: to use DOMDocument and DOMXpath classes you need to install [libxml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.libxml.php) extension. if `'//*'[@id="vpa1"]'` xpath expression did not work, then you need to check source html and your xpath expression [good tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/)  [xpath 1.0 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to first find the div with the specified id string using the following command (which uses the [simple dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)):

```
$div = $html->find('div#'.$divId)
```

and then to use the div variable to access more things inside.